# How can I do things after getting the install folder name and before the install starts

Tags: inno-setup

I need to implement the following sequence in my Inno Setup install after the user select the install folder, but before the installation starts. So that I can cancel if the following conditions are not met:

- Check that file Table.dbf exists
- if not send message to user and cancel setup
- Install Setup_Test.exe
- Install Setup_Test.ini
- Run Setup_Test.exe
- Check if File Setup.err has been created by Setup_Test
- If yes send message to user and cancel install otherwise start install proper.

I am new at Inno setup, and I am struggling to implement this, can anyone help, please

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`PrepareToInstall` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) for this purpose.

You can use it like:

```pascal
[Code]

function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  if not TableExists('Table.dbf') then
  begin
    Result := 'Table Table.dbf does not exist, cannot proceed with install.';
    Exit;
  end;

  if not SetupTest() then
  begin
    Result := 'Setting up test failed, cannot proceed with install.';
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

---

The `TableExists` and `SetupTest` are, of course, stubs. If you need a help with their implementation, ask a separate question.

---

When the `PrepareToInstall` returns non-empty string, the Inno Setup aborts with a message like:

[image]

Comment: Well sort off. These files need to be copied before other new files are installed, so that is a problems. Any ideas

Comment: Well, that's what the `PrepareToInstall` does. As the name ("prepare to isntall") says, it's called before anything is installed.